# Verify integrity Ceritifcate { RSACryptoServiceProvider - SHA1 - thumbprint }

Tags: c#, certificate, sha1, verify, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a little problem. I want to verify the integrity of a certificate.

So I did this code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 

SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
AsymmetricAlgorithm rsaAlgo = certificatEnCours.PublicKey.Key;
byte[] data = null;
byte[] hash = null;

string keyPublic = "";
string signatureLikeInteger = "";

bool verif = false;

// ------------- PART 1 -------------

signatureLikeInteger = certificatEnCours.Thumbprint;

data = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureLikeInteger);

// ------------- PART 2 -------------

hash = sha1.ComputeHash(certificatEnCours.RawData);

keyPublic = rsaAlgo.ToXmlString(false);

csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

csp.FromXmlString(keyPublic);

// ------------------------------

verif = csp.VerifyData(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), data);
```

My problem its that i already have the value "`false`" on my variable "`verif`".

Comment: could someone please reformat the question. It's awfully hard to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual question here.  You are right that you are unconditionally ignoring the initial value of verif.   More importantly, have you considered using X509Certificate2 to do verification?:

```
X509Certificate2 x2 = new X509Certificate2(certificatEnCours);
bool verif = x2.Verify();
```

I think this is wiser than re-inventing the wheel.

EDIT: If you are verifying a chain of certificates I believe you want to use [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx)
and in particular the [ChainStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.chainstatus(VS.100).aspx) property.